# Count the number of applications in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I have this table above and the task is "How many applications from last year came from people with experience between 5-15 years working for companies hiring more 300 employees".

I tried to settle this problem by using Pivot Table(in picture below). But I think It`s not the problem. Maybe I did something wrong. Is there any ways to solve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: A problem you need to figure out is how to deal with the range given by companies in the third column.  ie a company 100-500, is that considered hiring more than 300?  I am making the assumption that you are equating size to hiring since there was no column in your table to indicate the forecast number of new hires.

Comment: Its a common assumption that when people say 15-30 that 15 and 30 are included in the range.  Are they included?

Comment: you will need a column that is numbers in order to deal with your 3rd criteria.  When you do, you can use the `COUNTIFS` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You need this to find that, "how many applications from last year came from people with experience between 5-15 years".*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Create Helper columns, as I did in Col AI & AJ.
- Formula in cell AI19:

  ```
  =IF(AND(YEAR(AG19)<YEAR(TODAY()),AH19>=$AJ$17,AH19<=$AJ$18),1,0)
  ```

***This considers all previous year's cells.***

- Final formula in cell AI25:

  `=COUNTIF(AI19:AI24,1)`

---

- Formula in cell AJ19:

  ```
  =IF(AND(YEAR($AG19)=2020,$AH19>=$AI$17,$AH19<=$AJ$17),1,0)
  ```

***This considers only last year's cells.***

- Final formula in cell AI25:

`=COUNTIF(AJ19:AJ24,1)`

---

*- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Bertha Aguilar ,,, keep asking ☺